# python ObjectListView negate filter

Tags: python, wxpython, filtering, objectlistview, objectlistview-python

I need some help with negate this filter for the ObjectListView.

```
def addFilter(self, text):
    # OLV.Filter.Predicate()
    meter_flt = OLV.Filter.TextSearch(self, text=text)
    self.SetFilter(meter_flt)
```

This works great, but if i try to filter like "chicken" then it's only show chickens. I want it to be reversed, so if i type chicken, everything apart from chicken should be displayed.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Filter.Predicate`](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/features.html#filtering)

> Filter.Predicate(booleanCallable) Show only the model objects for
>   which the given callable returns true. The callable must accept a
>   single parameter, which is the model object to be considered.

Following is a code snippet for handling multiple text to be excluded from the list of items.

```
def __init__(self):
    self.text_list = [] # list of text to be excluded
    self.SetFilter(Filter.Predicate(self.filterMethod))

def addFilter(self, text):
    self.text_list.append(text)
    self.RepopulateList() # so that our filter_method is applied again

def filterMethod(self,obj):
    for text in self.text_list:
        if {YOUR EXCLUSION LOGIC HERE}:
            return False
    return True
```